# Why Benchmark runs six(?) times

Tags: go

This code ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/aRVv38HBaPN)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

var test = make([]int, 0)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(testing.Benchmark(testThis))
}

func testThis(b *testing.B) {
    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

has next output:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
2000000000           0.00 ns/op

Program exited.
```

Why there are six `[]` inside output?

This code ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/ABUs-IJCwP_G)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var test = make([]int, 0)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

has single output (and it's clear for me):

```
[]

Program exited.
```

Comment: @JörgWMittag your comment isn't unclear. Same as your undervote. And my question is clear. How can I ask the author of benchmark if I don't know who it is? By the way, have not found `go` tag inside your top tags.

Comment: You might be better off reading this article by Dave Cheney first https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go

Comment: I am sorry, I am not a native speaker of English, and thus I am having trouble understanding your comment. I have never heard the term "undervote" and I don't understand why you think that I would have such a thing. Also, I don't understand what the top tags have to do with your question, especially since I wasn't able to find [tag:go] among your top tags either. (Although [tag:go] *is* in the top 20% of my tags, so if you didn't find it, there seems to be some error in the [so] engine, which explains why I couldn't find it in yours.) I am assuming that you got that code from somewhere, so you

Comment: might find some documentation there on who wrote it, and why they chose to write it this way. Like I said, 6 repetitions seems *much too few* to get any meaningful results, so I would really like know the answer also. I would expect at least 10000 repetitions, if not more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a benchmark function. This need to execute code multiple times to get a result which is kinda meaningful.

Also your Benchmark is not implemented like the benchmark should be programmed:

> The benchmark function must run the target code b.N times. During benchmark execution, b.N is adjusted until the benchmark function lasts long enough to be timed reliably. 
>   -- https://golang.org/pkg/testing/

So Benchmark will check the run time and will adjust the b.N to get a good and useful benchmark.

When you just print b.N you get an output like this:

```
1
100
10000
1000000
100000000
2000000000
2000000000
```

So in each of the 6 iterations the benchmark is telling you to run a foor loop b.N times.

Sadly you can not use a correct example in the playground because they take to long. But correct would be:

```
func testThis(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        fmt.Println(test)
    }
}
```